# Drop down terminal in elementary OS?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

In GNOME there is the drop down terminal extension that appears when you press `'` (the key above tab).  Can I do the same with the terminal program shipped with elementary OS Freya?  If not, is there an application I can download to have a drop down terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a drop down terminal you can either use [guake drop down terminal](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/drop-down-terminal-guake-070-released.html)

or [terra: mix of guake and terminal emulation](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/terra-drop-down-terminal-emulator-with.html)

Comment: So, I want to thank you greatly for sharing this.  I have successfully added my own shortcut, and changed the height, but I cannot find where I could change the width.

In the 'src/DropDown/PantheonTerminalDropDownWindow.vala' class, I see on line 34 there is something describing width, but as I am remedial student of programming, I am not sure what to do.

Could it be in another class file?

Answer (score 7):

I have a drop-down branch for pantheon-terminal

https://code.launchpad.net/~parnold-x/pantheon-terminal/drop-down

**How to compile:**
`sudo apt-get build-dep pantheon-terminal`
`bzr branch lp:~parnold-x/pantheon-terminal/drop-down`
`cd drop-down && mkdir build && cd build`
`cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr ..`
`sudo make install`

Then you can start it with `pantheon-terminal --drop-down`

You can configure the height and the key in the (default is F12) `src/DropDown/PantheonTerminalDropDownWindow.vala` class

Comment: I don't know how to compile things in Linux, but I'm always trying to learn new things. I'll look into learning how to compile and check out your link. Thank you.

Comment: Added compile instructions. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Djax I am get an error on running the command 
`cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr ..`
`package 'vte-2.91' not found`

Comment: i have already adapted it for loki. I assume you use freya. Go back to revision 704 then. `bzr revert -r704`

Comment: @Djax I tried changing the key from the `src/DropDown/PantheonTerminalDropDownWindow.vala` file. Changed it to F1 But it made no effect. the terminal still opens with F12 only.
Also I would like to open it with 'fn+F1' key. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Any reason it is not picked up by the mainline pantheon?

Comment: FYI, the shortcut uses [this function](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/functions.html#Gtk.accelerator_parse), and the forked code might have just used [this post](https://esite.ch/2011/02/global-hotkeys-with-vala/). I changed the key to "<Control><Shift>space", but I had to first unbind my guake hotkey or it would fail at launch.